# Using a single carret character as the fold character in Neovim using Lua

Tags: neovim, folding, lua, foldtext, foldmethod

I am using Neovim v0.9.5 and configured this editor using Lua.

I'm searching for a way of using a single caret down (▾) character for folds.

Here is what is currently used by Neovim by default.

```
** Heading title folded---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
** Another heading unfolded
   Some content
```

Here is what I want

```
** Heading title folded ▾
** Another heading unfolded
   Some content
```

Also, notice the space afte the `d` letter and the caret character.

What is the Lua code that I can append to my `init.lua` file in order to achieve this goal?

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? If one of the answers solves your problem maybe could accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It let others know that it is worth reading and allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: The answer did not seem to work as intended, but I need to create a reproduction of the issue in an isolated environment. I simply did not have the time to do that but this is planned for the week-end. Thank you for the follow up.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Take your time we will continue to help when it is further clarified :-)

Answer (score 0):

If VimScript I would do:

```
set fillchars+=fold:\ 

function! MyFoldText()
  let line = getline(v:foldstart)
  subistitute(line, '\s*$', '', 'g')
  let line = line . ' ▾'
  return line 
endfunction

set foldtext=MyFoldText()
```

Or in "pure" lua:

```lua
vim.opt.fillchars:append({fold = ' '})

function myfoldtext()
  local line = vim.fn.getline(vim.v.foldstart)
  return line .. ' ▾'
end

vim.o.foldtext = 'v:lua.myfoldtext()'
```

I you want this to apply to only some `filetype` then the code should be put in the corresponding `filtype.lua` file and use local options:

```
vim.opt_local.fillchars:append({fold = ' '})


function myfoldtext()
  local line = vim.fn.getline(vim.v.foldstart)
  return line .. ' ▾'
end

vim.opt_local.foldtext = 'v:lua.myfoldtext()'
```